# Files Bookmark missing

Tags: nautilus, 17.10, files, shortcuts, bookmarks

my Files bookmark/shortcuts is missing, how to fix this?

[image]
   [image]
I want like this

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to get it back in place.